# How to run zsh and tmux with xterm-256color by default

Tags: zsh, tmux

I am using ubuntu gnome 14.04 and I want to have tmux and zsh opened when I start a new terminal.

For now, in my preference of the terminal, I run tmux by default.

In the ~/.tmux.conf file I have this :

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```

It works but I have a problem with colors so I need to use `TERM=xterm-256color tmux` to run tmux. I tried to replace the command launched by default but it produce this error : `no such file of this type`.

I tried to run zsh by default and I added this in my ~/.zshrc :

```
if [ "$TMUX" = "" ]; then TERM=xterm-256color tmux; fi
```

It works but it launch zsh then it launch another process with zsh again. It's not very clean and when I try to close the terminal, it say than I have an active process running.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually `tmux` should get the `TERM` parameter from your terminal emulator. So you could just set it to `xterm-256color` in your its configuration.

If this does not work for some reason, you can start `tmux` like that

```
tmux -2
```

The parameter `-2` forces `tmux` to assume 256-color support. Additionally you can set `default-terminal` in your `~/.tmux.conf

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: `tmux -2` works. I already had `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in my `~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: ...followed by tmux kill-server && tmux

Answer (score 2):

For proper installation, follow this order:

1. Install **zsh**
2. Run **zsh** from your terminal/bash
3. Set **zsh** as default terminal/bash
4. Setup **tmux** to run as default

---

After zsh is installed, run it from terminal

```
$ zsh
```

now set **zsh** as default Shell with

```
$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

*Note that you must be on zsh when typing this command (tested this on my Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS - trusty)*

SO, now you've setup the default Shell... 
All you have to do now is setup **[tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43604)** as default, and it will load automatically **zsh** instead of the Bourne Again Shell (Bash).

To [setup tmux as default](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Start_tmux_on_every_shell_login), put this in your ~/.zshrc before your aliases; the code for other shells is very similar:

```
[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux
```